# How to tell m2eclipse not to add the JRE as a dependency

Tags: eclipse, java-me, maven, m2eclipse

It seems that m2eclipse automatically adds the JRE as a dependency to a project.

On a JavaME project however I need to be able to disable that. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with M2Eclipse but I imagine the project build path is still managed in the same manner as a standard Eclipse installation. If this is the case then you should be able to change the project dependencies by doing the following:

1. 'Project' menu > 'Properties'
2. Select the 'Java Build Path' section
3. Select the 'Libraries' tab and from there you can edit the library dependencies

Additionally, you will probably want to alter the settings under the 'Java Compiler' section  to better match your target environment.